# python polynomial by category

Tags: python, polynomials

I'm new to python and trying to recreate an analysis from excel. My goal is to predict what the month end volume would be for any given business day. I want to get a trend equation for volume by day of the month (business day). Y is volume and X is business day in the month.

```
Days    Percent     Category
1       0.2748       Apple
2       0.3388       Apple
3       0.4000       Orange
4       0.4584       Orange
5       0.5140       Apple
```

The data is a trend of performed + scheduled volume recorded for each business day. It starts of low and then by the end of the month reaches 100% of actual volume or close to it.  For example, today is the 13th business day in May. The trend equation (z) gives 75%. I'd apply this against today's total to figure out the month end. Hope that made sense.

I was able to write a simple code in python that got me the z value for one category. The data has multiple categories. How do I productionalize this for multiple categories? I would like to save this data and report it using another tool.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\HawthornTrend.csv')

df1=df.rename(columns = {'Days':'x'})
df1=df1.rename(columns = {'Percent':'y'})

X=df1['x'].values
Y=df1['y'].values

X=X.reshape(81,1)
Y=Y.reshape(81,1)

X1 = np.array(df1['x'])
Y1 = np.array(df1['y'])
z = np.polyfit(X1,Y1,3)
p = np.poly1d(z)
p(13) ## values needs to be stored for reporting.
```

Comment: As I'm reading, it's not clear to me what category you are able to "[get the] z value for" and how that category relates to other categories you need. What are the categories? Do you mean `p(13)` is one category? Or that one indexed value from the resultant variable `p` is a category?

Comment: Sorry. I did not include the category in this data. It would be something like this Category Date Percent

Comment: Edited to include category.

Comment: Got this working by using a groupby. I'd like to add the business day to the data set. Any idea on how to do that?